# How to create HL7 ACK messages in nHAPI

Tags: nhapi

I have created an HL7 response message(ADR_19) by using nHAPI in C#.

How can I add an ACK message in the response HL7 message?

Comment: its too late to ask question, but could you please help me regarding with using nHapi with c#

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the terser supplied by nHapi. A while ago I've posted an example for using the terser to create an Ack message:
http://www.dib0.nl/code/63-creating-a-hl7-acknack-message-in-net-using-nhapi

Good luck!

Comment: sorry but can i have the link of your sample? i know its too late but im a little bit new in nhapi. thanks